# Twitter API on Windows NT Server not working

Tags: windows, twitter, twitter-oauth

I don't know what I'm doing when it comes to OAuth and twitter APIs so I've followed [this tutorial](http://zadroweb.com/your-twitter-feed-is-broken/) and I'm able to get this working on a Linux server.  However I cannot on a Windows server.  It throws the coded error message.

**Oops, something went wrong with our twitter feed...**

`if (!$tweet_flag) {
    echo $tweets = '<ul class="twitter_stream twitter_error"><li>Oops, something went wrong with our twitter feed - <a href="http://twitter.com/'.$twitter_username.'/">Follow us on Twitter!</a></li></ul>';
}`

Is there something that would cause there to be an issue?

Comment: what is the coded error message?

Comment: I just updated the post with that.

Comment: It looks like the URL isn't being created properly - it's literally trying to look up a timeline for a twitter user with the screen name `$twitter_username`

Comment: Updated, but that's not the issue.  I think it's something to do with the API according to the full code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found another solution:

http://f6design.com/journal/2013/06/20/tweetphp-display-tweets-on-your-website-using-php/

This worked fine on the site.